# Text argument is not passed correctly to hovertemplate in plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I create the barchart below with a custom hovertemplate but instead of my `text` I get a `"text"` when I hover over the bars.

```
Cum4c<-structure(list(Country = c("United States Of America", "Mexico", 
                                  "United Kingdom", "Brazil", "Germany"), Deaths = c(91765, 31887, 
                                                                                     31134, 29081, 22546), lab = c("91,765", "31,887", "31,134", "29,081", 
                                                                                                                   "22,546")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"))
    
    fig1 <- plot_ly()%>%
      add_bars(data = Cum4c, x = ~Country, y = ~Deaths,
               text = ~ paste("<b>Country:</b>", Country, "<br><b>Deaths:</b>", lab),
               hovertemplate  = paste('%{text}<extra></extra>'),
               colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436","#3e5b84","#028c75"),
               color = ~Country
               
               
               
      ) 
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,title=list(text="worldwide,by selected territories and period",x = 0,y=1,font=list(size=10)),
                            font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
                            legend=list(y=1.2,x=0,title=list(text='<b> Top 5 </b>')),
                            
                            yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",
                                         #dtick = 250000
                                         showgrid = T,gridcolor = "#a2a2a2", showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
                            xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = T,showticklabels = F,tickangle=45, showgrid = FALSE))%>% 
      
      config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
      config(displaylogo = FALSE)
    fig1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to achieve your desired result:

1. Get rid of `text` and instead use `hovertemplate = ~paste("<b>Country:</b>", Country, "<br><b>Deaths:</b>", lab)`
2. Get rid of `hovertemplate` and use `hoverinfo = 'text'` instead.

Both approaches will give you the same result.

```r
library(plotly)

fig1 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(
    data = Cum4c, x = ~Country, y = ~Deaths,
    hovertemplate = ~paste("<b>Country:</b>", Country, "<br><b>Deaths:</b>", lab),
    colors = c("#60ab3d", "#6bbabf", "#c4d436", "#3e5b84", "#028c75"),
    color = ~Country
  )
fig1

fig1 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(
    data = Cum4c, x = ~Country, y = ~Deaths,
    text = ~ paste("<b>Country:</b>", Country, "<br><b>Deaths:</b>", lab),
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    
    colors = c("#60ab3d", "#6bbabf", "#c4d436", "#3e5b84", "#028c75"),
    color = ~Country
  )
fig1
```

[image]